# How to convert a pdf file from a URL to base64 encoded string

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

So i have a link for a pdf file like this

```
https://layout-upload.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/docs/pdf/2019/11/21/sample.pdf
```

and i was wondering is there a way to convert that url to a base64 encoded string like so:

```
JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOfCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDMgMCBSL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nD2OywoCMQxF9/mKu3YRk7bptDAIDuh+oOAP+AAXgrOZ37etjmSTe3ISIljpDYGwwrKxRwrKGcsNlx1e31mt5UFTIYucMFiqcrlif1ZobP0do6g48eIPKE+ydk6aM0roJG/RegwcNhDr5tChd+z+miTJnWqoT/3oUabOToVmmvE...
```

i tried using toDataURL() but to no avail can anyone tell me how to do this with pure javascript without 3rd party library.

thanks

Comment: so what do you want to convert? In the headline you ask how to convert a file, in the question you talk about a URL? And what problem did you encouter converting whatever to base64? It's usually a simple function call.

Comment: @jps basically i wanted to convert the file from a remote server and not from my machine, not the link, to base64. i tried using using the fetch api then turn it to blob but got blocked by cors is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @dunhilblack Blocked by what?